# Why am I getting a communication Link failure

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using netbeans to build my application and I am trying to connect to my database. I have downloaded the jdbc file and linked this to my files. When I run the following code I get the following failure...

```
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

The code I am using below. Can anyone try and work out why I am getting this error, I feel it is something stupid I am missing but i have never had this problem before.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.*;

public class LoginAttempt {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/projectDB", "root", "");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println("-------------------");
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }



    }
```

Comment: please check on google for some nice tutorial on how to make jdbc connection..

Comment: 8888 is a **very uncommon** port for a mysql Database. Verify the ports bound with a `netstat -na` and check my.cnf / my.ini for correct port

Comment: Yes, usually MySQL runs on port 3306.  8888 is typically used by application servers.

Comment: okay thanks guys I will try these things